# How to implement a gui for yaml configuration in sonata admin?

Tags: symfony, user-interface, yaml, sonata-admin

For my current project it will be helpful to have an gui (simple form) where some defined yaml configuration file can be edit in the sonata admin backend.

In the admin dashboard I'd like to have group with settings. There I wanna have some links to edit some different config files in the backend.

What is the preferred or best practice to implement such a feature. Or is there any comparable existing feature or bundle out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've implement my first version of the [SensiYamlGuiBundle](https://github.com/sensi/SensiYamlGuiBundle.git) and share it on github. 
It's runnable and works together with SonataAdminBundle or as standalone.